# Conditional Expectation of Multiperiod Binomial

Tags: expectation, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution

I am given a discrete-time process ${X_i}$ where
$X_{i+1} = uX_i$ with probability $p$ and $X_{i+1} = dX_i$ with probability $1-p$. $X_0$ is equal to $x_0$ as well. Stated another way, $X_{i+1} = X_iu^{I_i}d^{1-I_i}$ where $I_1, I_2,...$ are iid Bernoulli RVs. Now for $n\geq1$ I need to compute 
$$E[X_n \mid X_{n-1}]$$
and
$$Var(X_n \mid X_{n-1})$$

This seems very simple to accomplish, but I am having trouble. So far, the direction I am taking is the following:
$$E[X_n \mid X_{n-1}] = E[X_{n-1}u^{I_{n-1}}d^{1-I_{n-1}} \mid X_{n-2}u^{I_{n-2}}d^{1-I_{n-2}}]$$

Following this, I am not sure if it's possible to bring in probabilities, and use Bayes theorem, or if I am even on the right track here. All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X_n|X_{n-1})=E(X_{n-1}u^{I_{n-1}}d^{1-I_{n-1}}|X_{n-1})=X_{n-1}E(u^{I_{n-1}}d^{1-I_{n-1}}|X_{n-1})$ because $X_{n-1}$ can be pulled out of the expectation. Now assuming that the $I_j$'s are independent of the $X_n$'s (without which the question cannot be answered!) we get $E(X_n|X_{n-1})=X_{n-1} (pu+(1-p)d)$. You can use a similar method to calculate $E(X_n^{2}|X_{n-1})$ and this gives you the variance also.

Comment: Use $p$ instead of $1/2$

Comment: Thanks Youmen for the comment.

Comment: Thank you both. To be clear, for $X_n^2$, it is only the $X_{n-1}$ term that is squared right? Not the $u$ or $d$ ?